# combine scripts in asp.net ajax toolkit

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

We are using version 3.0.20229.0 of the asp.net ajaxControlTookKit (before .net 3.5 sp1).  I was wondering if I can combine our custom javascript files into the ScriptResource.axd that the controlTookKit creates.  I've found this article (http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2007/06/11/script-combining-made-easy-overview-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit-s-toolkitscriptmanager.aspx)
which tells me that I need to add the scriptCombine attribute to the assembly file.  We are running a WebSite project, how can I add this attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to add the scripts as resources to a seperate library and reference them from there to take advantage of the script combiner.

**Edit to provide an walk through**

Create a new Class Library project (called for example "CombinedScipts"), remove the default class.

Add a reference to both the **AjaxControlToolkit** and **System.Web**

Add your JS files to the project, and change their Build Action property to "Embedded Resource".

Open the AssemblyInfo.cs file

Add the following:

```
// You need to add a web resource call for each JS file in the project
[assembly: WebResource("CombinedScripts.Console.js", "text/javascript")]
[assembly: WebResource("CombinedScripts.Utilities.js", "text/javascript")]
// Not setting IncludeScripts or ExcludeScripts marks all scripts as
// combinable.
[assembly: AjaxControlToolkit.ScriptCombine()]
```

Add this library as a reference in your web site project.

In your project, you can then add the following between the ToolkitScriptManager tags:

```
<Scripts>
  <asp:ScriptReference name="CombinedScripts.Console.js" 
                       assembly="CombinedScripts" />
  <asp:ScriptReference name="CombinedScripts.Utilities.js"
                       assembly="CombinedScripts" />
</Scripts>
```

Not forgetting to ensure that the CombineScripts property of the ToolkitScriptManager is set to true.

This then results in one call to something like:
    /pageName.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField&[...]

Which will have your combined scripts in, with comment delimiters like:

```
//START CombinedScripts.Console.js
[...]
//END CombinedScripts.Console.js
//START CombinedScripts.Utilities.js
[...]
//END CombinedScripts.Utilities.js
```

Comment: do you have any examples regarding this approach?

Comment: Sorry, I was writing the walk through as you commented.

Comment: Thanks you very much.  .NET 3.5 sp1 provides a much cleaner solution to this problem: http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-SP1/video-296.aspx .  I guess I'll wait until we upgrade our framework then.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yep, can't deny that the 3.5 SP1 updates make this a whole lot easier.